# Given 2 subspaces ,need to prove $dim(U \cap W) \not= 2$ (simple)

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given 2 subspaces , $U=\{(x,y,z,t) \in \Bbb R^4 | x-z+2t=0 \}$ and $U=\{(x,y,z,t) \in \Bbb R^4 | y-z+t=0 \land z=2x  \}$ prove that none of the statements are true
>
> $1) v=(1,-1,2,3) \in U \cap W$
>
> $2)dim (U\cap W)=2$
>
> $3) \Bbb R^4 = U \oplus W$

first statement is simply not true because $v \notin U$ so it is not possible

now for the others first I tried finding the spans so for $U$ we have $x=z-2t$ let $z= \alpha_2$ , $y= \alpha_1$ and $t=\alpha_3$ so the general solution set is $\{(\alpha_2 -2 \alpha_3,\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)\}$ so the span is $Sp(U)=\{(1,0,1,0),(-2,0,0,1),(0,1,0,0)\}$ from here we get that $dimU=3$

same goes for $W$ , $z=y+t$ let $y= \beta_1$ and $t=\beta_2$ so we get $z= \beta_1 +\beta_2$ and $x=\frac{1}{2}\cdot(\beta_1 +\beta_2)$ the general solution set is $\{(\frac{1}{2}\cdot(\beta_1 +\beta_2), \beta_1,\beta_1 +\beta_2 , \beta)\}$ from here the span is $Sp(W)=\{(\frac{1}{2},1,1,0) ,(\frac{1}{2},0,1,1) \}$ so $dimW=2$

from here we can say that statement 3 is wrong because $dimU+dimW=5\not=4$.

my question is how do I solve the second one? how do I find the intersection and is my way correct? thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the dimension of $W_1+W_2$.

You can leverage that
$$dim(W_1+W_2) = dim(W_1)+dim(W_2)-dim(W_1 \cap W_2)$$
You can get a feel for why this is morally right if you think about a Venn diagram with some overlap between $W_1$ and $W_2$

Comment: my question is how can i use this formula in my case ? how can i find the intersection?

Comment: Ah that's the fun thing, don't! You have $dim(W_1)$ and $dim(W_2)$ and the dimension of the sum should be straightforward, what's left is what you want.

Comment: thank you for the quick help ! :) 
is my answer correct that the intersection is equal to 1 not 2? I put the way I did it in the comment below

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches here.

You could just compute the intersection, which would amount to solving a $3x4$ homogeneous system of equations. You'd get one degree of freedom in the solution, and, hence, a subspace of dimension $1$.

Alternatively, you could use the dimension formula in the other answer. It is a significant shortcut since you already know $\dim{U} + \dim{V} = 5$. What remains to be determined then is $\dim{U+V}$, but this is easy. As the sum contains $U$, its dimension should be at least 3. By quick inspection, you can find a vector of $W$ which is not in $U$. Thus, the desired dimension is 4.

Comment: I got the $dim(U \cap W) =1 $ because i solved for $dim(U+W)$ and $U+W=Sp(U \cup W)$ i solved the homogeneous equations and got 4 opening and 1 free variable so the $dimu+w=4$ is that correct? did I miss anything or do it the hard way? ( the homogenous system I solved was $4x5$ matrix but obviously since we are in $\Bbb R^4$ one vector is free